# How to use AWS Java SDK to fetch objects list with query as s3api?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm developing with AWS java SDK. I would like to get an object list with a filter like filter by last modified date. I can see this feature on s3api as below

```sh
aws s3api list-objects 
            --bucket "myS3-BucketName" 
            --query "Contents[?LastModified>=`2018-02-01`].{Key: Key, Size: Size, LastModified: LastModified}" 
            --max-items 10"
```

I can't find a similar solution in Java SDK. How can I get this work with Java SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) of the AWS SDK for Java, I created the following utility method:

```
/**
 * Gets S3 objects that reside in a specific bucket and whose keys conform to the 
 * specified prefix using v2 of the AWS Java SDK.
 * <br><br>
 * The objects returned will have a last-modified date between {@code start} and 
 * {@code end}.
 * <br><br>
 * Any objects that have been modified outside of the specified date-time range will 
 * not be returned.
 *
 * @param s3Client The v2 AWS S3 client used to make the request to S3.
 * @param bucket   The bucket where the S3 objects are located.
 * @param prefix   The common prefix that the keys of the S3 objects must conform to.
 * @param start    The objects returned will have been modified after this instant.
 * @param end      The objects returned will have been modified before this instant.
 * @return A {@link Stream} of {@link S3Object} objects.
 */
public static Stream<S3Object> getObjects(S3Client s3Client, String bucket, 
                                          String prefix, Instant start, 
                                          Instant end) {
    return s3Client.listObjectsV2Paginator(builder -> builder.bucket(bucket)
                   .prefix(prefix).build())
            .stream()
            .map(ListObjectsV2Response::contents)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .filter(s3Object -> {
                Instant lastModified = s3Object.lastModified();
                return !start.isAfter(lastModified) && !end.isBefore(lastModified);
            });
}
```

The following code is logically equivalent to your example:

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.create();
String bucket = "myS3-BucketName";
Instant before = Instant.parse("2018-02-01T00:00:00Z");
Instant after = Instant.MAX;

Stream<S3Object> firstTenObjects = 
    getObjects(s3Client, bucket, "", before, after).limit(10);
```

You can use the following methods to get the data you're looking for from each `S3Object` in the `Stream`:

- [`S3Object#key`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#key--)
- [`S3Object#size`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#size--)
- [`S3Object#lastModified`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#lastModified--)

Comment: Hi @jacob-g, thanks for your solution. One thing I would like to confirm whether this method is filtering at local?

Comment: @RayChen It is; from what I can see, the AWS Java SDK doesn't support filtering remotely, but it shouldn't be *that* much more expensive.

Comment: Hi @jacob-G, we change to use S3 notification + Lambda since we do have lots of objects. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @JacobG. by "filtering remotely" you mean that the records are filtered on AWS side and only qualifying records are returned to the client? This is basically what I wish to happen, because the number of qualified records is tens (if not hundreds) of times smaller than the total number of records

Comment: @mangusta That's correct. I haven't stayed too up-to-date with the AWS SDK for S3, so I'm not sure if that functionality was ever added.